# Correlation matrix variance

Tags: statistics, random-variables, correlation

> The correlation matrix off the random variables $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4$ is $$
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         1 & \rho & \rho^2 & \rho^3\\
>         \rho & 1 & \rho & \rho^2\\
>         \rho^2 & \rho & 1 & \rho \\
>         \rho^3 & \rho^2 & \rho & 1\\
>         \end{pmatrix},0<\rho<1$$ 
>   Each random variable has variance $\sigma^2$. Find the variance of $\bar{Y}_4$.

The answer given is $\bar{Y}_4=(\frac14+\frac{3\rho}{8}+\frac{\rho^2}{4}+\frac{\rho^3}{8})$

I do not know how to get this solution. My intructor does not offer any explanation, and any terms that I try to look do not result in anything useful

Comment: By $\bar{Y}_{4}$, do you mean $\bar{Y}_{4}=(1/4)(Y_{1}+Y_{2}+Y_{3}+Y_{4})$?

Comment: The answer should presumably depend on $\sigma^{2}$ in some way but your formula doesn't?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Probably yes, for your first comment, and definitely yes for your second.

Comment: Can you express $\bar{Y}_{4}$ as $AY$ for some matrix $A$?  Can you find the covariance matrix of $Y$?  Do you know how to compute the covariance of $AY$?